# 404 when requesting url of saved image in media directory using django rest framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-media

I am developing a django rest api using the django rest framework. The rest api manages clothing items to be shown in an android application and has a model named `Clothing` which has an `ImageField` for showing the clothing item. From the django admin, I can add an image and save the `Clothing` model instance by clicked the save button below, which I do click and then get a success message:

[image]

I then check my media/clothing/ file which is configured to save the static files and see that the image has indeed been saved in this location:

[image]

Now, back to the admin, when I navigate back to the newly created Clothing model instance it has a path showing where the image is currently being stored:

[image]

When I click on it I get a 404 page not found (the X's in the url replace the actual numbers):

[image]

I'll show my setup for managing static files just in case it is needed:

> urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add-clothing/$', views.AddClothingView.as_view(), name="add_clothing_image"),
    url(r'^list-clothing/$', views.ListClothingView.as_view(), name="list_clothing"),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

> settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),)
```

The image is in the correct location when saved from the django admin, however when an attempt to access it from it's url is made, there is a 404, why and how do I fix this?

Comment: The urls.py you are showing appears to be inside your app, not at the top level. The error page shows that the only URLs you have defined at top level are /admin/ and /clothing/.

Comment: Also note, serving media like this only works in development. In production your web server needs to be responsible.

Comment: And finally, this has nothing whatsoever to do with the rest framework.

Comment: How would I let my web server handle this?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/  (that's about static files rather than uploaded media, but the principle is the same).

Comment: But if I follow the docs it should work even though this is uploaded media?

Comment: And how do I fix this for development? You say they need to be defined at the top level?

Comment: Yes, obviously if you want /media to work you need to define that in the top-level urls.py.

Comment: What would be the second argument for `url(r'^media/catalog/', )`

Comment: Ok I got it. Thanks

Comment: Tom Finet, what was the second argument?