# Django - serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'documuent_root'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-media

im trying to set up media file path / images for DRF but its not working and i cant figure out why.

i get this error:

[image]

```
serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'documuent_root'
```

I am on mac runing django 1.11 DRF w/ python 3.6.

I have moved the settings urls to top level by why way of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46120150/404-when-requesting-url-of-saved-image-in-media-directory-using-django-rest-fram) so i am one step closer although i still cant figure out why my links show 404 when i click on them.

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'src')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = 'localhost:3000', #whitelists the localhost to run
```

**views.py**

```
from accounts.api.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework import generics, mixins, permissions, viewsets
from books.models import Books
from books.api.serializers import BooksSerializer


class BookViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes      = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly]    # authentication_classes  = []
    serializer_class        = BooksSerializer  # necessary

    queryset                = Books.objects.all()
    lookup_field            = 'id'
    search_fields           = ('user__username', 'content', 'user__email')
    ordering_fields         = ('user__username', 'timestamp')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from rest_framework import routers
from books.api.views import (
                BookViewSet)

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'books', BookViewSet) # --> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/books/api/books/


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),

  ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, documuent_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a typo actually. You were using **`documuent_root`** , but it should be **`document_root`**.
So, change to

```
urlpatterns = [
    .... other patters,
    ]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: fml. i didnt catch that...and neither did my spell check.

Thank you!

Comment: it makes me wait 5 minutes. got you covered